# Jquery ui slider move to the next value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a sample image of what i'm trying to accomplish

[image]

Say I click from 150 value the handle should only move to 50 and not jump to 150. I click again it move from 50 to 100.

The other way around, say the handle is on value 150 then i click on value 5, it should not jump directly to 5 it should move from 150 to 100.

How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
var valMap = [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150];
value = 0;
var slider = $("#slider").slider({
    disabled: false,
    animate: true,
    min: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        slider.slider("option", "animate", "slow");

    },
    change: function () {

        var Slideval = $(this).slider('value');
        console.log(Slideval, value)
        if(value < Slideval) {
            console.log("incremented")
        } else if(value > Slideval) {
            console.log("decremented")
        }
        value = Slideval;
    }
});
```

Here's a sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/endl3ss/jNwww/21/

Comment: Would be helpful to link to an example on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle

Comment: look also this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5xMMz/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the slider too much, but here is a working solution based on your specification:

http://jsfiddle.net/5xMMz/11/

and here is the full code for reference

```
    var valMap = [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150,500,1000,5000];
    value= 0;
    var lastSlideValue = 0;
    var internalSlideCalling = false;

    var slider = $("#slider").slider({
    disabled : false,
    animate : true,
    min : 0,
    max : valMap.length - 1,
    slide : function(event, ui) {
        slider.slider("option", "animate", "slow");
    },
    change: function(){

        var Slideval = $(this).slider('value');

        if (!internalSlideCalling)
        {
            if (Slideval>lastSlideValue && lastSlideValue < $(this).slider('option','max'))
            {
                Slideval = lastSlideValue+1;
            }
            else if (lastSlideValue > $(this).slider('option','min'))
            {
                Slideval = lastSlideValue-1;                
            }
            lastSlideValue = Slideval;
        }

        console.log(Slideval, value)

        if(value < Slideval) {
          console.log("incremented")
        } else if(value > Slideval){
          console.log("decremented")
        }
        value = Slideval;

        if (!internalSlideCalling){
            internalSlideCalling = true;
            $(this).slider('value',Slideval);
        }
        else 
            internalSlideCalling = false;
    }
});

$("#slider").slider('values',valMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use event which will raise when we move slider and then set the value for slider.We can manually set the slider value.

This is event code

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
            // code
        },




$('#id').slider("value",value); //using this we can set the slider value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#slider").slider({
    step: 50
})
```

Here is the link for more information - http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

Comment: That won't do, the handle will still move from 20 to 150 when i click 150 value and ignore the rest of the value.

Comment: In windows 7 there is an audio icon in the menu tray. I'm achieving the same thing like that using jquery ui slider.